# Changes in local commit disappeared after merging with development branch

Tags: git

I was making some changes in a remote local branch (feature/FooUpdates) that tracks a remote branch of the same name, when I realised there were changes in the development branch. To get the changes from development in my feature/FooUpdates branch I ran the following commands:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Add bar"
$ git checkout development
$ git pull -p
$ git checkout feature/FooUpdates
$ git merge development
```

The changes from development appeared in my local feature/FooUpdates branch but the changes made with the "Add bar" commit have vanished

Running git reflog showed:

```
$ git reflog
b6f9576t (HEAD -> feature/FooUpdate, origin/development, origin/HEAD, development) HEAD@{0}:        merge development: Fast-forward
80aa2asa (origin/feature/FooUpdate) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from development to feature/FooUpdate
b6f9576t (HEAD -> feature/FooUpdate, origin/development, origin/HEAD, development) HEAD@{2}: pull -p: Fast-forward
80aa2asa (origin/feature/FooUpdate) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from FooUpdate to development
438ea3f5 (FooUpdate) HEAD@{4}: commit: Add bar
```

I can get my changes back no problem by resetting to the "Add bar" commit but unsure why this happened as there were no merge conflicts. Any explanation would be much appreciated so I can avoid this in the future

Comment: I think you are confused with the branches. Do you have a branch called `FooUpdate` and another called `feature/FooUpdate`? Just in case, your changes are not lost, you will be able to see them in branch `FooUpdate` by doing `git show 438ea3f5` (if your description of the commands that you posted is accurate) or checking out _that_ branch.